# IOException inside print or println

Tags: java, exception, io

Most of the IO operation requires try catch block or throws . Why is try catch or throws not required for System.out.print or println. If there is any exception inside these methods how would i know whats the exception and how to catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for an error by calling

```
System.out.checkError();
```

[javadoc of `PrintStream.checkError()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#checkError%28%29) says:

> returns `true` if and only if this stream has encountered an
>                 `IOException` other than
>                 `InterruptedIOException`, or the
>                 `setError` method has been invoked

If you really want to monitor exceptions of `System.out` you could set your own `PrintStream` to `System.out` and override the methods you are interested in.

Comment: System.out.checkError();
it returns a true if there is an exception else false, how would i know which Exception.

Comment: You can't find out. The exception is caught silently and the trouble flag is set: `catch (IOException x) { trouble = true; }`